# How do I get intellisense for me?

Tags: wpf, stylesheet, styles

I'm a web designer learning WPF. One of the things I need to learn are styles.

When I was using CSS all I had to do is go to a site like w3 and see what styles were supported for various tags. The examples from WPF seem to rely on intellisense instead of a fixed list of styles.

Other people seem to be able to add `<Setter Property="BackgroundHover" Value="Red">` without an issue. When they do it `BackgroundHover` is supplied by intellisense. They don't have to search for it. This is not the case on my machine. Since I can not find a published list of properties to set for the style I'm left up the proverbial creek.

How do I either fix intellisense for styles or find out what styles are supported for a given third party UserControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For intellisense to work for properties set that way, it needs to know what type that the setter is being applied to.  So in the style, set the `TargetType` to the type that you will be applying the style to and intellisense can offer suggestions to the values.

```xml
<Style TargetType="MyType">
    <Setter Property="MyProperty" Value="MyValue" />
</Style>
```

You'll also want to make sure you have the right versions of everything on your machine.  The same libraries, same versions of Visual Studio, the same code, etc.  Also there should not be any other errors in the XAML file.  Intellisense should be working then.

Comment: That's the thing - I'm doing this. In fact I can get latest and compile so the code on my machine is the same as the one to my right. The machine to my right will be able to use intellisense and I will not.

Comment: @JSWork: Does the machine to your right have the same environemnt?  Same version of visual studio?  Same settings (as far as you know)? Same libraries?  Is there an error elsewhere in your markup?

Comment: @Jeff: That may very well be it! It seems to be working on 2010 SP1. I don't have SP1. Hopefully an upgrade will solve the issue.

Comment: @JSWork: I'm not sure if updating Visual Studio to SP1 will necessarily fix the problem, but it couldn't hurt to update anyway.  My understanding is that intellisense just needs the assemblies to figure out what types and members are available so it can give the information it does.  But if it works, then that's great.  :)

Comment: We'll find out first thing on Monday.

Comment: @Jeff: Upgrading to SP1 solved the issue. I could either mark this one as correct or wait for you to put in a separate answer and mark that one as correct instead.

Comment: @JSWork: Rather than putting a separate answer, I've moved what we discussed into the existing one.  It really should have worked just by doing this alone.  The version of Visual Studio normally wouldn't be the deciding factor, SP1 or not.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this in the [description of VS 2010 SP1 download](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509):

> #### Style IntelliSense
>
> Lets you easily modify styles that you already have in XAML. Now you get IntelliSense for properties and their values in a style that is based on the TargetType.